# Assigning value to undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was writing some code in JavaScript. When I accidentally came across this.

```
undefined = 'some value' //does not give any error

true = 'some value';   //gives error

null = 'some value';   //gives error
```

How is it that first statement is valid whereas the other two are invalid. From what I know both undefined, true, and null are values you can assign to some variable, so all these should be invalid statements.

Comment: *how is it that first statement is valid whereas the other two are invalid* that's what the spec says. You should use strict mode, it makes a bit more sense (can't assign to `undefined`).

Comment: note that even if it does give no error, `undefined`'s value will stay undefined. Which is not a case inside a function (with the keyword `var`, or else it will be no different from first case)

Comment: @alex I just wanted to know why the assignment works is all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined):

> `undefined` is a property of the global object; i.e., it is a variable
>   in global scope. The initial value of `undefined` is the primitive value
>   `undefined`.

Hence, you can assign the value to `undefined` unlike `true` and `null` which are reserved keywords. Note that this is the same case with `NaN` as well which is again not a reserved keyword and hence, you can assign any value to it.

---

Just to add more to this, it doesn't matter even if you are assigning a value to `undefined`, it will not write to it as it is a readonly property.

Quoting from MDN again.

> In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), undefined is a
>   non-configurable, non-writable property per the ECMAScript 5
>   specification. Even when this is not the case, avoid overriding it.

[image]

---

Prefer using strict-mode in your JavaScript by declaring `"use strict"` at the very top of the file or inside a function to avoid such things. Using something like

```
"use strict";
undefined = 'test'; //will raise an error, refer to [1]
```

> <sup>[1]</sup> VM1082:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read
>   only property 'undefined' of object '#'

Comment: When I tested your last case in the browser, I don't see an error raised. I tried in node as well. No error is raised by the value of undefined is unaffected.

Answer (score 5):

This is because **undefined is not a reserved word in JavaScript**, even though it has a special meaning. So it can be assigned a value and the whole statement is valid. Whereas `true` and `null` are reserved words and can't be assigned values.

For reference: [JavaScript Reserved Words](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I quote directly from the MD Js docs.

> While it is possible to use it as an identifier (variable name) in any
>   scope other than the global scope (because undefined is not a reserved
>   word), doing so is a very bad idea that will make your code difficult
>   to maintain and debug.

```
//DON'T DO THIS

// logs "foo string"
(function() { var undefined = 'foo'; console.log(undefined, typeof undefined); })();

// logs "foo string"
(function(undefined) { console.log(undefined, typeof undefined); })('foo');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Answer (score -1):

You can not declare a variable with the name of reserved words(keywords) in any language either it's scripting or programming.

if you want to use this you can use `_` underscore at the very first of the varibale name.

like: _true , _null or _anythingwhatyouwant

Comment: Better to use decent naming conventions instead of hacking out the reserved keywords which is not bad, but might lead to confusion later.

Comment: But `undefined` *is not* a reserved word, so this answer is totally unrelated to the question.